# Bar chart annotation in ChartWrapper

Tags: python, google-visualization

I am using ChartWrapper for generating bar graph of my data set. The data set comes from dataSourceUrl (an NOT an internal dataTable). Here is the source code snippet:

```
var chart_wrap6 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType' : 'BarChart',
            'refreshInterval': 5,
            'dataSourceUrl' : 'http://yourcompany.com/test.py',
            'containerId' : 'bar_chart3',
            'options' : {title: 'Title', vAxis: {title: 'Start Time'}, hAxis: {title: 'Time in minutes'}  }
            });
chart_wrap6.draw();
```

I want to label the bars. I looked at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Labels which suggests to use role:annotations But I am not sure where and how to use it my javascript code. A sample code will be greatly appreciated.

I am using gviz_api in my python code

```
data_table = app.get_chain_elapsed_time_stat(chain_name)
print data_table.ToJSonResponse(req_id=req_id)
```

Thanks
Abhijit

Comment: It would appear there is no way to do this from javascript.  `ChartWrapper`'s `getDataTable()` method returns null for external data sources, as you've probably already discovered.  You'll need to add your annotations from python code.  It would probably help to have some more python code.  I'm not a python programmer, but I can see enough to know that probably isn't going to be enough to help.